# Remove explicit casts from autocomplete of enum

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When using the autocomplete of enums, the default option is an explicit **cast** in many cases, which is usually not the desired one. So if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> I'll get the undesired autocomplete.

Consider the the `Visibility` enum. If I type the letter `c` - instead of offering `Collapsed`, Visual Studio offers `(char)`.

[image]

There are many more offered for different letters:

[image]

How can I remove those **cast** options from the autocomplete menu so that if I type the first letter of an `enum` value I'll get the desired one?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2022 The document does not specifically mention the ability to remove a specific cast option. I suggest you type one more letter or go to DC to make a suggestion.